# Why widget does not update?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I'm making a dictionary with a Daily Remember Word and i want to display it on widget. Widget does not update when i change next word. How can a make the widget update. Please help me! This is my class:

```
public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
private SharedPreferences sharename, sharedescribed;
private SharedPreferences na, dess;



@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        SharedPreferences sharename = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String na = sharename.getString("thename", "null");


        SharedPreferences sharedescribed = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String dess = sharedescribed.getString("thedescribed", "null");


        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.main2);

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, na);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview2, dess);


        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);





}
```

}